# How to check how many non-alphanumeric characters on a string

Tags: java

i'm trying to check how many non-alphanumeric characters can be found on a string
for example:

```
String message = "i'm a keyboard!!!"
```

i want to check how many "!" and " ' " can be found on that string, not only those, but any symbol.

Comment: What have you tried? Perhaps replacing all alphanumeric characters with nothing and testing the length of the result?

Comment: Iterate through the string and count them...

Comment: use Regex.. with them, you will be able to get the required result in less time..

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but plenty of ideas: [Java regex: check if word has non alphanumeric characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506154/java-regex-check-if-word-has-non-alphanumeric-characters?rq=1)

Comment: Have an array of symbols, then iterate your your String, if it's equal to any of the symbols in the array, increment count

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular expressions would be good for this. Try just replacing alphanumeric character with nothing and taking the length.

```
pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]*"
newString = message.replaceAll(pattern, "")
return newString.length
```

Comment: If you also include underscore as an alphanumeric, you can use `String pattern = "\\w";` instead.