# How do I use the IsAlphabetic binary property in a Java regex match?

Tags: java, regex, properties, binary

I'm using this pattern to check if a string starts with at least 2 alphabetic characters in front a colon:

```
string.matches("^\\p{IsAlphabetic}{2,}:")
```

but I get the following exception thrown at me:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown character property name {Alphabetic} near index 16
    ^\p{IsAlphabetic}{2,}:
    ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1730)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.charPropertyNodeFor(Pattern.java:2454)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.family(Pattern.java:2429)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:1848)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1769)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1477)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1150)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:840)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(Pattern.java:945)
    at java.lang.String.matches(String.java:2102)
```

even though the specification of the Pattern classes states:

> Binary properties are specified with the prefix Is, as in IsAlphabetic. The supported binary properties by Pattern are
>
> - Alphabetic
> - Ideographic
> - Letter
> - ...

and the section **Classes for Unicode scripts, blocks, categories and binary properties**
lists

> `\p{IsAlphabetic}       An alphabetic character (binary property)`

Comment: it works for me. Note that matches method tries to match the whole string.

Comment: It doesn't matter if I enclose `\\p{IsAlphabetic}` in a character class with `[]`.

Comment: @Avinash: what Java version and OS are you on?

Comment: What Java version are you using? The pattern works in 1.8.

Comment: Your pattern works correctly in this online tester: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html.

Comment: The error message shows "Alphabetic" - did you post code from another location in your program - not the place where the error occurs?

Comment: I'm running Java version 1.8.0_40 (oracle-jdk-bin-1.8.0.40 on 64 bit Gentoo Linux).
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)

Comment: Contrary to @laune's comment on a now-deleted answer, the [Java 7 API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#ubpc) seem to say that `\p{Alpha}` *is* equivalent to `\p{IsAlphabetic}` when the `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag is specified

Comment: @laune: I think, the character property itself is called Alphabetic, but in order to use it as a binary property, you have to specify the Is….  But in the exception, it uses the character property name again.

Comment: Is your project configured to work with Java 8? Is it able to compile something like `Predicate<String> empty = String::isEmpty;`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Try matching  String s = "äö:"; using IsAlphabetic and IsAlpha and Alpha.

Comment: @freedio Yup, this is confusing. So some old Java version seems to be the only explanation?

Comment: @all: Thanks a lot for all the comments!! `\\p{Alpha}` and `\\p{IsAlpha}` both work, so I stick with one of these, since they seem to be equivalent.

Comment: OK, Java 7 doesn't have IsAlphanumeric yet. fails with the error as reported.

Comment: @Pshemo: Good point! I'm working in eclipse, and in fact, my default compiler compliance level is set to 1.6 (the reason being that I'm also developing for legacy Android projects) — so the JVM I'm running on is actually irrelevant.  But since I've found a viable solution with `\\p{Alpha}` I won't go through the hassle of reconfiguring and recompiling my 20+ projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works and returns true using java 1.8.

```
String s = "äö:";
System.out.println(s.matches("^\\p{IsAlphanumeric}{2,}:"));
```

Note that the forms available in Java 1.7 - Alpha, IsAlpha - do not necessarily include characters not in US-ASCII . This returns false:

```
String s = "äö:";
System.out.println(s.matches("^\\p{IsAlpha}{2,}:"));
```

But note that this works in 1.7 and returns true:

```
String s = "äö:";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile( "^\\p{Alpha}{2,}:",
                     Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS );
Matcher mat = pat.matcher( s );
System.out.println(mat.matches());
```

Comment: The form with `\p{Alpha}` (but not the one with `\p{IsAlpha}`) *does* work if the `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag is specified for the pattern, as documented.  Tested on Java 8 against the input given in this answer.